# Play framework, parse json array from request

Tags: arrays, json, scala, playframework

How could I parse an array of `json` objects to scala `List` or `Array`?

For now I have a code that parses the single object:

```
{"id":1,"name":"example1"}
```

And this is the code:

```
def exampleAction = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    for {
        id <- (request.body \ "id").asOpt[Int]
        name <- (request.body \ "name").asOpt[String]
    } yield {
        (exampleService.create(Example(id, name)) map { n => Created("Id of Object Added : " + n) }).recoverWith {
            case e => Future {
                InternalServerError("There was an error at the server")
            }
        }
    }.getOrElse(Future { BadRequest("Wrong json format") })
}
```

But how should I change it to parse json requests like this:

```
{[{"id":1,"name":"example1"},{"id":2,"name":"example2"}]}
```

I guess function `map` should be used somewhere.

Comment: The very last line is not valid JSON, but without the outer braces `{}`, it is. I'm assuming that's what you meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your controller shouldn't need to worry about validating and mapping specific class fields, that's the model's job. Assuming the `Example` case class you appear to be using, you can easily create a `Reads[Example]` using the `Json.reads` macro provided by Play. The implicit `Reads` should be placed in the companion object of the corresponding class, so the implicit can be picked up from anywhere. You can also create more custom `Reads` if you need to by reading through the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#toolbar), but for now we'll stick to the basics.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Example(id: Int, name: String)

object Example {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Example] = Json.reads[Example]
}
```

Then, in your controller, you can use `JsValue#validate[A]` to attempt to de-serialize the entire model at once. Doing so returns a `JsResult[A]`, which can either be a `JsSuccess[A]` that holds the de-serialized model, or a `JsError`. We can `fold` the result to handle both cases.

```
def exampleAction = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
  request.body.validate[Example].fold(
    error => Future.successful(InternalServerError("JSON did not validate.")),
    example => {
      // Do something with the case class
      exampleService.create(example).map { 
        // ...
      } recoverWith {
        // ...
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Now, you can easily change the above controller to handle a array instead of a single model by changing:

```
request.body.validate[List[Example]]
```

And the second part of the `fold` method you will get a `List[Example]` that you can work with.

---

Note that in your error cases, instead of using `Future { ... }` to wrap what are essentially constant values that do not block anything, you can instead wrap them in `Future.successful(...)` to avoid dispatching trivial work out to the `ExecutionContext`.

Comment: Was this deprecated in 2.6, or is there an import statement one needs in the controller performing this method? On this line `request.body.validate[Example].fold(` IntelliJ underlines the `validate` part, saying it cannot resolve it.

Comment: @NateH06 see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#scala-controller-changes for what was changed around this stuff in play 2.6.

Comment: Is there any "simple" way without having to create extra class? just put the result in List[Map[String, String]] perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing a little from Michael's answer we can simplify the controller code further by using a version of [`parse.json` that is parameterized in its type](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.BodyParsers$parse$@json[A](implicitreader:play.api.libs.json.Reads[A]):play.api.mvc.BodyParser[A]).

Assuming the `Reads` exists:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Example(id: Int, name: String)

object Example {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Example] = Json.reads[Example]
}
```

To handle a json array of Example objects you can simply use `parse.json[List[Example]]` as your body parser and then `request.body` will be a `List[Example]`:

```
def exampleAction = Action.async(parse.json[List[Example]]) { implicit request =>
  val examples: List[Example] = request.body

  // ...
}
```

Play will automatically return a `400 Bad Request` if the body posted to this endpoint is not a valid json array of example objects.

Comment: When I do it this way, IntelliJ complains about the `request.body` part, saying "Expression of type AnyContent doesn't conform to expected type List[Example]"

Comment: you left off the parse.json portion. `Action.async(parse.json[List[Example]])`. The default body parse in Play will give you AnyContent.

Comment: also, try compiling outside of intellij (with sbt directly). Intellij has been known to get some things wrong from time to time.

Comment: No, didn't forget it and definitely copy and pasted your code, swapping out `Example` with my case class. I tried compiling with SBT on its own, and it gave a compile error with no message. I also tried compiling in the browser, and it gave me a bit more: `type mismatch; found : play.api.mvc.AnyContent required: List[models.jsonmodels.Example]`

Comment: "it gave a compile error with no message" This seems odd. Is it possible you're missing a Reads for your case class?

Comment: I should correct myself and say, no message of any value: `"[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 27 s, completed Aug 26, 2017 4:12:33 PM`
But yeah, I'm sure, copied your case class example word for word, swapping the name and mine has two Strings instead of an Int and a String

Comment: Maybe post a pastebin of your full source? Or a sample GitHub repo.

Comment: It's roughly like this: https://pastebin.com/HC6Fbb6M, but I found a workaround, see below.

Comment: Leave off the type on the implicit request parameter. Or change AnyContent to what it should be.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that did it, thanks! I had also found a workaround and added it to the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I tried following the accepted answer and greggz' to the letter but couldn't get them to compile.

I'm building an answer off of gregghz' answer though. So... you'd definitely need to make the case class and companion object as he did:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Example(id: Int, name: String)

object Example {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Example] = Json.reads[Example]
}
```

But your controller method can be even simpler, especially if you don't want to mess around with the Async. This worked for me because I was sending an HTML `form` from the client end, taking each `input` and sending ONLY that back to this method. There may be shortcomings to this way, and I'd appreciate hearing about them in the comments, but all you have to do from there is:

```
def exampleAction = Action {
    implicit request: Request[AnyContent] => {
      val jsonBody = request.body.asJson
      val myContent : List[Example] = jsonBody.get.as[List[Example]]
      // ... do rest of work here
      Ok("Json parsed")
    }
  }
```

Comment: This will return a 500 Internal Server Error if the body isn't json or doesn't match the Jon schema of Example.

Comment: The reason I want to parse the array manually is because I want to return 200 in all ways, just different content result accordingly. All the answers doesn't help at all, is it that difficult to parse a Json Array in play framework scala? I am new to scala and it seems very difficult as I can't find any solution to such simple problem after 5 minutes of Googling